# Слова, указывающие на прямую речь

Tags: прямая-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, указывают ли слова "спросит", "ответ" на прямую речь?
Например: *Оппонент наивно спросит*: далее сам вопрос. Или: *Ответ будет следующий*: текст ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Да, сами слова могут указывать на прямую речь. Однако во втором предложении" Ответ будет следующий:..." слово "ответ" не указывает на прямую речь, т.к. в предложении не указано лицо.

Comment: Т. е., я Вас правильно поняла, что в таком предложении, после двоеточия кавычки не нужны? Ведь хотя лицо и не указывается - оно подразумевается.

Comment: Кавычки не нужны. Если вы приведете контекст, возможно и ответ будет другим. Но в данном предложении кавычки не нужны. После двоеточия раскрывается сам ответ, необязательно, чтобы он принадлежал лицу.К тому же, согласно правилам, если не указывается, кому принадлежит речь, кавычки не ставятся.

Comment: Ответ примитивный: «А зачем лезть на Северный полюс за топливным газом, бурить вечную мерзлоту при температуре минус 70 ⁰С и тянуть трубу за 3 тысячи км, если можно поставить компактную буровую рядом с центром региона или области и поставлять газ для всего этого региона? Если это реально воплотится через 10 лет, то кому нужны будут газовые «севера» России?» Я оформила, как прямую речь, потому что мне кажется, это авторские слова.

Comment: Повторюсь: если не указано, кому принадлежит речь, кавычки не ставятся. В вашем предложении не указано, кому принадлежит речь. Кавычки не нужны. Если же из предыдущего контекста ясно, что это именно слова автора, кавычки нужны.

Comment: Серж, ну вы же не правы... Откуда вот это: "Если не указано, кому принадлежит речь, кавычки не ставятся"? Кавычки можно ставить, можно не ставить.

Comment: См.: Академический справочник. Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь.Д.Э.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно оформлять прямую речь, а можно не оформлять.

Comment: Совершенно с вами согласна,  " на все сто!" (как Иван Бездомный с Берлиозом).

Comment: Это большая редкость, сударыня ))

Answer (score 1):

Прямая речь - это **дословное высказывание лица**, при этом перед прямой речью находится текст, который мы **условно** называем авторскими словами, но он может иметь различный вид.

1) Ответ примитивный: «А зачем лезть на Северный полюс за топливным газом, бурить вечную мерзлоту при температуре минус 70 ⁰С и тянуть трубу за 3 тысячи км, если можно поставить компактную буровую рядом с центром региона или области и поставлять газ для всего этого региона? Если это реально воплотится через 10 лет, то кому нужны будут газовые «севера» России?»

Это **правильное оформление**, так как распространенный текст сохраняет авторскую стилистику и может принадлежать конкретному лицу:

2) В других случаях возможны варианты.   Например, высказывание обычно оформляется **в виде БСП со значением изъяснения**, если сказуемого в словах автора выражено глаголом НЕСОВЕРШЕННОГО вида и  обозначает НЕОДНОКРАТНО ПОВТОРЯЕМОЕ действие:

Решительно скажу: едва другая сыщется столица, как Москва. Иду я и думаю: давно я здесь не был. Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться? Он рассуждал так: отцу раньше шутя можно было прожить.

Как БСП может оформить предложения с глаголами **в будущем времени**: оппонент наивно спросит, ответ будет следующий.

Comment: Вера, вы сами сказали: ''дословное высказывание лица''. Если это дословная цитата, то другое дело. А здесь не указано, эти слова принадлежат автору, или это просто высказывание. К примеру, вы пишете статью, раскрываете вопрос и далее отвечаете на вопрос этими словами: ''Ответ примитивный''? Далее вы поставите кавычки?

Comment: Серж, не надо быть формалистом, в структуре подобных предложений позиция и желания автора очень важны. Автор просто с помощью одного оформления может указать вид информации (дословная или недословная), то есть выбрать ту грамматическую форму, которая в данном случае ему удобна. (Кстати, в БСП кавычки не ставят, с кавычками это уже упрощенное оформление прямой речи).

Comment: О кавычках в БСП я не говорил. я лишь сказал,если неизвестно лицо, кавычки не нужны. И это согласно правилам. Но кавычки будут нужны, если действительно это слова автора. Зачем просто так, не разобравшись, где попало ставить кавычки?

Comment: Серж , представьте, что вы близко к тексту пересказываете чьи-то слова, сохраняя стилистику говорящего, но всё-таки не дословно. Иди другой вариант: вы просто представляете, фантазируете, что он вам это говорит.  И вот как автор, вы можете оформить высказывание так, как вам нравится, это ваше авторское право. Помните у Тургенева: Никогда он ничего подобного не сказал, – промолвил Аркадий. – Ну, не сказал, так мог и должен был сказать в качестве поэта.

Comment: Вера, я повторюсь: если доподлинно известно, что это прямая речь, кавычки нужны. Пусть даже это из предыдущего контекста. а вот если не дословно, то кавычки ставить нужны. Для чего тогда правила. Пусть даже сохраняя стилистику автора. Вера, и здесь я опираюсь на правило. Если автору этого вопроса известно, что это слова  автора, пусть ставит кавычки.

Comment: Для чего тогда правила? Правила надо отменить, а вместо них ввести РЕЕСТР РАЗРЕШЕННЫХ ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИХ ФОРМ по различным темам, связав их с содержанием высказывания и дополнив цитатами из классической и современной литературы.

Comment: Вера, ну это уже не наша прерогатива. Мы тут, увы, бессильны!

Comment: Правила тоже надо применять разумно, без лишнего фанатизма и формализма, и тогда автор будет управлять правилами, а не правила автором. Даже оставаясь в рамках правил,  можно чувствовать себя достаточно свободно.

Comment: Так давайте использовать правила по своему усмотрению: ставлю знаки препинания там, где хочу, потому что я так считаю нужным.

Comment: ''Даже оставаясь в рамках правил, можно чувствовать себя достаточно свободно''. Вы правы. Прежде чем ставить те или иные знаки препинания, надо понимать их значение и их роль. Надо разобраться в тексте и контексте, а потом уже решить, какой знак ставить. Особенно это касается спорных случаев.